# Is there a tennis Grand Slam winner with a lower career high ranking than #15?

Tags: history, trivia, tennis, ranking

I was involved in a discussion on the "worst" singles Grand Slam winner and we were trying to think of the player with the lowest career high ranking as a possible candidate.  [Mark Edmondson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Edmondson) was dug up with a career high ranking of #15 (rather than his ranking when he won, which was #212 and the lowest ever).

Are there any, male or female, with lower in the era of rankings?

Comment: You aren't likely to find anyone with a career ranking of worse than #15 because of the points structure in place for grand slam competition. A slam winner earns 2,000 pts. The current #15 in the world is Youzhny with 2,145 points. So it's hard to be ranked outside of the top 15 just from the slam victory alone.

Comment: These days, sure, but they've only been worth 2000 points [since 2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Rankings#Previous_points_distribution_.28until_2008.29).

Comment: That's true - I did a quick scan of names on the page linked at the end of this comment here and didn't find any names that didn't at least reach either top 10 or top 5 (or better) in the world rankings. I think you found the highest with Mark Edmondson.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Slam_men's_singles_champions

Comment: If you want to expand this to the female singles champions - it looks like Australian Chris O'Neil never made it above a world ranking of #80 and she won the 1978 Australian Open: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_O%27Neil_(tennis)

Comment: I was already keen on including female winners - see the last line in the question - so feel free to make that an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Australian Chris O'Neil never made it above a world ranking of #80 and she won the 1978 Australian Open: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_O%27Neil_(tennis)